# Using Core Data in app without UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, persistent-storage

I have a simple to do list application. It uses dynamically generated text fields spaced programmatically for the tasks (I didn't use UITableView because of some custom animations and whatnot that I want to use).

In the app the user can create multiple lists (home, work, school, etc.) each with their own tasks.

**I want to use Core Data to store the information**

Saving the information is straightforward enough but updating my Core Data objects (List and Task) are where I'm getting stuck. Also how, with Core Data, to associate in a specific tasks with a specific list.

[image: My Data Model]

let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally clear on your question, however, the task of updating a managed object is straightforward.  When you're doing an initial add (similar to an "insert" in SQL) you might use code like this:

```
NSManagedObject *obj;
obj = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"UserData" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[obj setValue:user forKey:@"userName"];
[obj setValue:goalCategory forKey:@"goalCategory"];
[obj setValue:goalDetail forKey:@"goalDetail"];
NSError __autoreleasing error;
[context save:&error];
```

That's about it for inserting a new item.  For updating after you're found the managed object you're working on, you just change the values in the managed object and use [context save:&error].  Here's an example:

```
UserData *uData = (UserData *) managedObj;
uData.itemName = nameText;
NSError __autoreleasing *error;
[context save:&error];
```

That's pretty much it.

As to the update, once you have selected the object(s) to be updated, they are contained in

```
fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects
```

which is an NSArray.  So, you might do something like this:

```
UserData *uData = (UserData *) [fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:3];
uData.completed = YES;
NSError __autoreleasing *error;
[context save:&error];
```

So, this would update the field completed in the UserData entity to be == YES for the object at index 3 in the fetchedObjects array.

I know there are other methods of updating and lots of options but I haven't found any need for them.  fetchedObjects is an array containing the items returned by your fetch; to update them, cast each object to the entity (which is defined as a NSManagedObject), make the change then context save..

HTH.

Comment: I updated my question to be more clear. The first code snippet you gave me makes sense. Saving the information I understand. It's the updating of a specific object (in my case a Task object once it has been edited or marked completed) where I get lost.

Comment: See revisions to response.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is `NSFetchedResultsController`. You can use it exactly like in the pattern suggested by the Xcode templates (you can look at it by creating a new project Master-Detail and checking "User Core Data").

You can device your object model (entity `Task`) with a string attribute for the name as well as a `NSNumber` boolean attribute for done etc. I also recommend a timestamp and maybe a serial number for ordering it (I find `NSOrderedSet` unreliable). Your entity `List` should have a to-many relationship to `Task`. Pretty straight forward.

```
List <---->> Task
```

The only difference is now to find the right object, because you cannot use `objectAtIndexPath`. You can use the index in `fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects` for that. Just make sure your objects are ordered as expected.

Comment: I've added an image of my Data Model so you can see what I'm doing. I've added the timestamp like you suggested, thanks for that. My question has to do with the NSFetchedResultsController you referred to. Could you explain a bit more how to use it?

Comment: Just start a new project by using the template as explained in the first paragraph. Read through the master view controller to see how the fetched results controller drives the data in the table view.

Comment: I did look at the template you mentioned above, It seems the techniques used are specific for using Core Data with UITableViews. Any resources I can look at that will help me know how to use Core Data without a tableview?

Comment: Of course, just use the help function in Xcode and look up NSFetchedResultsController. In principle, use the lazy instantiation from the template and the above-mentioned `fetchedObjects`. It's really simple, once you get the hang of it.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, think is it good idea to use Core Data for your project. If your model is light and simple, maybe it will be better to use plists.
If you choose Core Data, just remember 2 rules:

1. Each thread owns separate `NSManagedObjectContext`;
2. Perform operations with context only in its thread.

And don't worry about optimizations now. Realize any scheme of updating your storage. Make sure it works. And then you should try some other update methods.

Comment: I think that Core Data is the best way to go because I have multiple custom objects that need to be stored, I added an image of my Data Model so you can see what sort of structure I am building and why I feel it is necessary to use Core Data.